# How to count all open forms of 1 specific class?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi

I have a few Form-classes that derive from `Form`. And I want to count all open form instances of 1 special class like Form2. It's a simple WinForms application (no Mdi).

- Form1 (main)
- **Form2** (can be many)
- Form3 (other forms)

The app can't be started multiple times. So it's just about counting the windows in this one application.

My ideas:

- Can `Application` give me a list of open windows ?
- WinApi, enumerate windows of 1 application ?
- put every new Form2 window into a list (*I wish to avoid that*)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Application.OpenForms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property like:

```
int form2Count = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form2>().Count();
```